# Perform in app force update using current and required build numbers

Tags: flutter, in-app-update, app-update

I want to force update my app.

Here's what I have done so far.

1. Obtained the current build version of my app using  **package_info_plus**
2. Obtained the enforced build version which I have stored in the firebase remote config. So I used this package: **firebase_remote_config**

I then compared the two build numbers to see if the update is needed. What should I do after that?

Here's my code:

```
 void initState(){ 
     super.initState();
     checkForUpdate();
    _initPackageInfo();
    _enforcedVersion();

if(int.parse(_packageInfo.buildNumber) > int.parse(enforcedBuildNumber))
{ 
    //How to force update? 


}
}

Future<void> _initPackageInfo() async {
    final info = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
    setState(() {
      _packageInfo = info;
    });
  }
Future<void> _enforcedVersion() async {
  final RemoteConfig remoteConfig =  RemoteConfig.instance;
  await remoteConfig.setConfigSettings(RemoteConfigSettings(
              fetchTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 10),
              minimumFetchInterval: Duration.zero,
            ));
  await remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate();
   setState(() {
     enforcedBuildNumber = remoteConfig.getString('enforced_build_number');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could display a non dismissable dialog which would ask the user to update the application with a redirection button to the device appstore.

By using a package such as [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) you can easily do that:

### Code Sample

```dart
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

// You can show a dialog like this
showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false,
  builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
    title: Text('Please update your app'),
    actions: [
      TextButton(
        onPressed: launchAppStore,
        child: Text('Open App Store'),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);

// Method to open the appstore
void launchAppStore() {
  /// Depending on where you are putting this method you might need
  /// to pass a reference from your _packageInfo.
  final appPackageName = _packageInfo.packageName;

  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    launch("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$appPackageName");
  } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
    launch("market://details?id=$appPackageName");
  }
}
```